# Custom babel plugin - cannot traverse (visit) JSXElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to write a custom babel transform plugin. When see the AST for a React component in [astxplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net), I see JSXElement in the tree as a node.

But when I try to log the path for the visitor **JSXElement**, nothing logs to the console.

React component

```
const HelloWorld = () => <span>Hello World</span>
```

Code to transform the component and log **JSXElement** while visiting

`transform.test.js`

```js
const { code, ast } = transformSync(HelloWorld, {
    ast: true,
    plugins: [
      function myOwnPlugin() {
        return {
          visitor: {
            JSXElement(path) {
              // nothing logs to the console
              console.log("Visiting: " + path);
            }
          }
        };
      },
    ]
  });
```

If it helps, I have the `transform.test.js` inside an ejected `create-react-app` project. CRA comes with built-in preset `react-app`.

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
```

I run the test with the command `jest transform.test.js` and I have `babel-jest` transform applied by default in CRA jest setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're passing the component to Babel instead of the code for the component, you need to transform the actual code as a string, for example, something like this:

````js
const { code, ast } = transformSync(`const HelloWorld = () => <span>Hello World</span>`, {
    ast: true,
    plugins: [
      function myOwnPlugin() {
        return {
          visitor: {
            JSXElement(path) {
              // nothing logs to the console
              console.log("Visiting: " + path);
            }
          }
        };
      },
    ]
  });```
````

Comment: That was it. Thanks @mitchell-hamilton.

Comment: I also had to use the plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` before my custom plugin but I can traverse JSXElement now.